# list of responses is not showing on dynamic content while working on power automate site

Tags: power-automate

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xumAd.png)

list of responses is not showing on dynamic content while working on power automate site. What should I do to make list of responses available?

Comment: The list of responses or the response details?

Comment: Provide clarity in your question and add more details.